# Control the compilation of various branches with SVN and Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins, build, continuous-delivery

I'm setting up a validation process of development code, which consists of daily Jenkins compile the branches opened in SVN and validate whether they are stable.

Today we work with 3 branches opened for maintenance, product developments and projects, so I have the following example:

```
branch_manutencao_4.2.x 
branch_evolutivo_5.0.x 
branch_projetos
```

Today I have a pipeline that makes the process, but I would like to create something that I pass on the branch as a parameter, so if I had to create a new branch, Jenkins understood.

I tried to use the plugin MultiBranches but haven't had much success. My idea was to create a file or job that the list was assembled dynamically.

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipeline projects support ☑ *This project is parameterized*.

- Add an [***Active Choices Parameter***](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin):

  *Name*: `Branch`

  *Groovy Script*:

  ```
  return [
    'branch_manutencao_4.2.x:selected', 
    'branch_evolutivo_5.0.x', 
    'branch_projetos',
    'New branch...'
  ]
  ```

  *Choice Type*: `Radio Buttons`
- Add an ***Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter***:

  *Name*: `New_Branch`

  *Groovy Script*:

  ```
  if ( Branch.equals('New branch...') )
    return '<input name=\"value\" type=\"text\">'
  else
    return ' by selecting <i>New branch</i> above...'
  ```

  *Choice Type*: `Formatted HTML`

  *Referenced parameters*: `Branch`

  *Omit value field* ☑
- In your Pipeline Script:

  ```
  if ( New_Branch?.trim() && Branch.equals('New branch...') )
    echo "New branch: ${New_Branch}"
    // ...
  else if ( Branch?.trim() && ! Branch.equals('New branch...') )
    echo "Existing branch: ${Branch}"
    // ...
  else
    echo 'No branch supplied.'
  ```